# Automatically Create New JIRA User Accounts

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jira

We have JIRA for our faculty/staff at the college I am applications developer for.  The JIRA is fine-tuned for them to report issues to maintenance and I.T.  We use LDAP for external authentication of user passwords.

Right now, if someone new joins our company, I have to manually add a new user to JIRA.  I am wondering if there's a way to create a batch process that checks the LDAP, and if there's a new user, automatically creates a user account on JIRA for them.  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

What version of JIRA are you using.
Version 4.3.x has simplified the user directory configuration quite a bit, including the support for creating a JIRA user at first login

Check out following article
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA043/Connecting+to+an+LDAP+Directory#ConnectingtoanLDAPDirectory-AddingUserstoGroupsAutomatically

Francis

Comment: We are using an old version of JIRA -- Enterprise version 3.13.5.  This may be another item I chalk up to my supervisor in support of us upgrading JIRA (which I'd like to do anyway to gain access to the iPhone JIRA apps that only support more recent versions of the software).

Comment: Have a look at following plugin: https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/4835?versionId=4836.  Although it's not indicated as compatible with 3.13.5, it is with 3.13.4.   You might check with the  plugin developer for more information